# Neovim assign shortcut for compiling and running a scala file

Tags: neovim

Currently, after writing a scala program I have to invoke the three commands:

1. File save
2. compile the file
3. run the program

How to assign a shortcut for steps 2 and 3 above?

Comment: Hi @prateek, are you still searching a solution to your problem? Could you tell us which part of your question is not already answered?

Answer (score 0):

If your command to compile is: `:scalac -classpath . %` and your command to run is `:terminal scala -classpath . %:r` to associate them to the shortcuts <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> respectively you could add the following lines in your `init.vim` file:

```
nnoremap <F7> :scalac -classpath . %<CR>
nnoremap <C-F5> :terminal scala -classpath . %:r<CR>
```

You could also configure Vim to associate `:make` to scalac that allow you to get the compiler error in the Neovim Quicklist (and to make use of the `autowrite` feature)

If you add the following lines to `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/scala.vim`

```
" Make that calling make automatically save the change in your buffers
setlocal autowrite

setlocal makeprg=scalac\ -classpath\ .
setlocal errorformat=%A--\ [%t%n]\ %m:%f:%l:%c\ -%#,%C%\\d%#\ %#\|%.%#,%C%\\d%\\+\ error%.%#
```

I had to transform the `scalac` output with `sed` (`| sed s/\x1B\[[0-9]\+m//g`) to remove the color escape characters for the `errorformat` to work.

And the following line in your `init.vim`:

```
nnoremap <F7> :make %<CR>
nnoremap <C-F5> :terminal scala -classpath . %:r<CR>
```